# Updating a database using arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, sql-insert

I'm trying to update a database using arrays, but I can't seem to do that. I can only update it using strings, and numbers, but not arrays. Then I tried to echo out the string, number AND the array, just to see if I made an mistake in making the array. Please take a look:

```
$string = "string";
$num = 10;
$array[0][0] = "array";

echo $string."</br>";
echo $num."</br>";
echo $array[0][0]."</br>";
```

output:

```
string
10
array
```

But inserting data into a table using mysql:

```
$table = "userLogin";
$column = "username";
```

Using string:

```
$query= "INSERT INTO $table($column)VALUES($string)";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Output in table:

```
string
```

Using number:

```
$query= "INSERT INTO $table($column)VALUES($number)";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Output in table:

```
10
```

But when you're using an array:

```
$query= "INSERT INTO $table($column)VALUES($array[0][0])";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Output in table:

There is no change. Why is that? I  figure that since all strings, numbers, and arrays can be echo, using the echo command, they can be use likewise when updating a database. But it seems like you can only update them using strings and numbers. Unless, I'm doing something wrong. If I'm doing something wrong, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using curly brackets? `$query= "INSERT INTO $table($column)VALUES({$array[0][0]})";` By the way, if those variables contain user input it's better to use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: **WARNING**: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: `echo $array."</br>";` does it not showing any php notice like this `Notice: Array to string conversion` because you can't echo array

Comment: @TomasoAlbinoni I tried it. Sadly, it didn't work. Also, I take all tags out of user input, so users can't inject database.

Comment: It should work with curly brackets. You could also try concatenation: `$query= "INSERT INTO $table($column)VALUES(" . $array[0][0] . ")";` You say you take out all tags, and I wonder what you mean by that. Are you sure you understand how SQL injection works? Just use prepared statements, it's not hard and you don't have to be creative with filtering user input anymore.

Comment: Forgot the single quotes: `$query= "INSERT INTO $table($column)VALUES('{$array[0][0]}')";`

Comment: Yes. Its not working with curly brackets. $query= "INSERT INTO userLogin(username)VALUES({$array[0][0]})";
$result = mysql_query($query); Isn't SQL injection hackers use to corrupt your database? But I thought they need tags to work. If I take out tags, would it not be possible to corrupt my database? Maybe I'm wrong. I haven't read too much about sql injection.

Comment: Definitely read about SQL injection, it's an important topic. And don't use a deprecated API. And use prepared statements. Good luck!

Comment: @TomasoAlbinoni Would it be okay if I just change all of my mysql to mysqli? That would make all the code newer versions, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79060/discussion-between-tomaso-albinoni-and-iscattered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP arrays-in-strings 201 (intermediate level): PHP's string parser is NOT greedy, and by default will ignore multi-dimensional array references inside double-quoted strings.

e.g.

```
$foo = array();
$foo[0] = array();
$foo[0][1] = 'bar';

echo $foo;          // output: Array
echo "$foo[0]"      // output: Array
echo "$foo[0][1]"   // output: Array[1]
echo "{$foo[0][1]}" // output: bar
      ^----------^
echo $foo[0][1]     // output: bar
```

If you want to use multidimensional arrays in double-quoted strings, then, as above, you have two choice: Don't, concatenate them into the string; or use the `{}` notation to force PHP to parse the ENTIRE array reference, not just the first dimension.

The specifics of your problem:

```
$query= "INSERT INTO $table($column)VALUES($array[0][0])";
```

actually becomes

```
$query= "INSERT INTO $table($column)VALUES(Array[0])";
                                           ^^^^^
```

where `Array` is an unknown/invalid field name, and `[0]` is a flat-out syntax error.